# How can I convert a pdf to a format that is compatible with iBooks

Tags: ipod-touch, iphone, pdf, books

I have a pdf file, which I would like to convert to iBook compatible format, which software can I use to do this? calibre seems to be too tough to work with

Comment: You know you can add PDF files to iBook, right?

Comment: yea, i know that we can add pdf files to iBooks, but it wud look like a pdf and letters would be too small to read :)

Answer (score 6):

The good news: you don't have to! iBooks will happily take PDF files and display them just fine and dandy.